# Can a user control style its parent window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

I have a user control that is displayed in a popup dialog using Prism's `PopupWindowAction`.  I don't want the window to be resizeable.  Is it possible to style this window from the user control?  I attempted to use this:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

but it is not working.

**Edit:**

Based on the accepted answer, I moved the style over to the user control that is defining the `IteractionRequestTrigger` and assigning the `PopupWindowAction`'s `WindowStyle`.

New code in calling use control:

Add Resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
        <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Popup Window declaration

```xml
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding InteractionRequest}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction WindowStyle="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">                
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <sharedV:InformationDialog />
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

Comment: Why not just set the `ResizeMode` on the window itself?

Comment: It would be nice to know why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your XAML doesn't work is:

- The style you created is explicit - it has a `x:Key`. Explicit styles have to be applied on the target element directly `<Window Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}" ... />`
- Even if you remove the `x:Key` and make it an implicit style, since it is defined in the `UserControl`'s resources, it will only apply to items below the UserControl in the tree.

In this case you might want to look at the `WindowStyle` property of the `PopupWindowAction`. You should be able to set the style there.

Comment: `WindowStyle` worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Children cannot directly change their parent's style since the visual tree model is designed to go from broad to specific (`Window` to `UserControl`...) with styles being inherited and overridden in that direction. That said, anything is possible because it's all just code!

This isn't a nice way to do it, but you can use the `Loaded` method of your `UserControl` in the code behind to do the work of navigating the visual tree to find the parent `Window` and forcibly set the `ResizeMode` property. You can do this using `this.Parent` and checking for when `is Window` is true, or you can use [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent?view=netframework-4.8).

XAML:

```
<UserControl Loaded="OnLoaded"></UserControl>
```

C#:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentParent = Parent;

    while (currentParent != null && !(currentParent is Window))
    {
        currentParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentParent);
    }

    if (currentParent is Window parentWindow)
    {
        parentWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that the answer would be something along these lines.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I chose the answer with no code behind, but since I'm sure this would work, I gave you an upvote.